# device-height is being removed from meta viewport tag

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework, viewport, meta-tags

In my HTML I am using following meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
```

Notice that `height` is set to `device-height`.

After deploying the HTML on android device using ionic framework, `height=device-height` is gone from the meta tag and tag simply becomes like this.(I am using chrome's inspect device tool to check it).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
```

What am I missing here? why `height` property from the `meta` tag is being removed and how do I prevent it from being removed?

Comment: Did you found a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: I did not. I fixed it though using viewport units.